# Android-Customized Dialog

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to know how to pass value to the custom dialog box from the activity.

Suppose I want to  pass  a text in the activity to the edittext box in the customized dialog box,then what should I do?

Comment: Show the code you currently have (where you create your dialog)

Comment: have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745651/bundle-names-annoying-issue) this might be your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... somewhere in activity....
private String myValue = "hello :)";
... somewhere in activity when you show dialog...
final View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
final EditText editTxt = customView.findViewById(R.id.edittext_in_custom_view);
editText.setText(myValue);
new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(customView).create().show();
....
```